# Why Java compiler restricts adding even the right type of element to the List when using wildcard with extends

Tags: java, generics

I understand the [**PECS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) rule with regards to extend and super from other posts, but I am a bit confused about the restrictions below code

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
integerList.add(1);
// integerList.add(3.14); => understandably this will not compile, 
// as we cannot add double to a list of Integer

List<? extends Number> numberList = integerList;
// numberList.add(3); => will not compile!
// Why the compiler cannot infer from the above line that 
// adding an Integer to a list of Integer is OK, the same 
// way it inferred that line 3 was not OK?
```

Are there any reasons why the compiler would impose the restriction on line 5, given that we are just trying to add an Integer to a list of Integers and there is sufficient information available to the compiler?

Comment: How do you expect it to know that `numberList` is a `List<Integer>` when you declared it a `List<? extends Number>`? For all the compiler knows, that's a `List<Double>`.

Comment: the same way it prohibited line 3 I assumed

Comment: @zencv But on line 3 it sees that you're trying to add a double to a `List<Integer>`. The compiler won't try to infer that you've assigned that list to `List<? extends Number>`. See my answer, the compiler is lazy and especially in this particular instance it would be crazy to bother.

Comment: The problem for the compiler is autoboxing and not generics, I answered your question in detail with examples of what the problem is and how to circumvent the problem. Generic type erasure can be a compile time warning, seldom a compiler-error. Typesafety should be taken seriously, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are effectively saying this is a List of **Something** that is a subclass of Number.

So that could be anything, what if it is a List of Doubles? List of BigDecimals? This is why adding Integers is not allowed.

If you want a List that can hold **any** Number, that is:

```java
List<Number> numberList = ...
```

In Java, there is no type-inference, except with Lambdas, so the information that the List is *acutally* a List of Integers is lost as soon as you cast it.

Comment: He's asking why the compiler (which knows what the actual type is) doesn't allow it anyway.

Comment: If the compiler did use its contextual knowledge to say "wait a moment, the static type is `List<? extends Number>`, but the actual type is `ArrayList<Integer>` so this can go through" then the compiler/language would become quirky/puzzling in several ways, i.e.  trying to wrap that apparently legal code into a function would fail (because the compiler would not be able to know the real type behind an argument). Kinda like what happens with a lambda and the "final or effectively final" rule for variable captures: you change an unrelated line and then the lambda doesn't compile.

Comment: You're right, that would be confusing and error prone at best. However, I would wish *some* inference. For example: if I check something with *instanceof* I would want that variable to effectively become that type without cast for the rest of the block, or until changed.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam `List<? extends Number> numberList = integerList;` Here the compiler does verify that `integerList` is indeed a list of **Something that extends Number**, did you mean to say that the compiler does not remember that information after that?

Comment: @zencv compiler doesn't know, if you changed `numberList` to another object. It only knows compile-time type, wicht is declared in the variable declaration section. It is impossible to know runtime type without running the program, isn't it?

Comment: @zencv Yes, after the assignment, the compiler only knows that *numberList* is declared as `List<? extends Number>`. What the *actual* type is, is "lost" at that point. This is actually what we want, so this is not a shortcoming of Java in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<? extends Number> numberList = integerList;
//numberList.add(3);
```

compiler doesn't allow you to add anything to `numberList`(other than `null` ofcourse) bcoz compiler doesn't have enough information about the type being referred to the by  `numberList`.

what if `integerList` was a list of double , take this example

```
void method(List<? extends Number> list){
        //list.add(5);
    }
```

there is no way for the compiler to know what you'll pass in ,all it knows is that `List` type must be `Number` or a subtype of `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
integerList.add(1);
List<? extends Number> numberList = integerList;
//numberList.add(3); // will not compile!
numberList.add(new Integer(3)); // will compile!
Integer three = 3;
numberList.add(new Integer(three)); // will compile!
```

This is because Integer is an object, which is a subclass of Number, while int is a primitive. Primitives are not classes and thus can't be subclasses. They are only autoboxed in 1 case, [casting from primitive to their exact Object-equivalents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

```
Integer threeInt = 3; //will compile
Long threeLong = 3; //won't compile
```

`3` is a number literal for a int, which is autboxed to `new Integer(3)`, [if and only if you are expecting an Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
longlist.add(3); //will compile

ArrayList<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();
longlist.add(3); //won't compile
longlist.add(3l); //will compile
```

This won't compile, because types don't match, the compiler can't cast from Integer to Long. Similiar in your case the compiler can't cast from int or Integer to Number. At runtime the information which generic type an object has is lost and at compile time the compiler doesn't know what you want him to do. You are giving him an int (primitve), but expecting an object of type number.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question in any way. My question is about the behavior of the compiler and any rationale behind it.

Comment: My answer is about the compiler and the rational behind it. All other answers are about the compile time of generics. Mine answers why the compiler doens't do what you want, simply test my code examples and understand them. Generics isn't your problem, it's autoboxing. My first line will compile. The compiler can't cast from int to Number and the specs link shows that in the specs, and the examples show what to do: Box the integer yourself.

Comment: `numberList.add(Integer(3)); // will compile!` Only if you create your own `Integer` method. Or you add the `new` keyword which you've deleted in one of your edits.

Answer (score 0):

Because in most cases there isn't sufficient information available to the compiler, and the compiler doesn't want to bother itself with such minor details (`javac` is quite lazy).

As far as it's concerned, even though you just declared it as an `ArrayList<Integer>`, it only looks at the `List<? extends Number>` part.