# Adding element to generic List via reflection in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic method for sub classes lists which add a new element no matter which of the sub class I choose.

for that matter I made an example that will be easy to understand.
There is A zoo container of giraffes and zebras lists. zebra and giraffe are both Animals. I needed to create a'mate' method  that will be able to get List of homo gene type meaning list of giraffe or zebra(but not both), and the mate method will add another animal of the type to the existing list (without copying) if there are more than 2 animals in the list.

so to solve this I thought to used reflection since I can not initiate a generic type in java(it is not allowed in java- new T() is not allowed). 
so I created an instance of the first element, and tried to add it to the list with  `animals.add(newAnimal);`.. however the compiler complains about it with the following error:

```
Error: java: no suitable method found for add(Animal)
    method java.util.Collection.add(capture#1 of ? extends Animal) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Animal cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Animal)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#1 of ? extends Animal) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Animal cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Animal)
```

I solve it by getting the add method at run-time using again, reflection, and it is working(the line in comment), however **I would like to know why the compiler does not allow me to use add for animal**, because I could not find the answer myself.

The code:

```
class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>{
    int numLegs;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Animal o) {
        return this.numLegs-o.numLegs;
    }

}
class Giraffe extends Animal{
    int neckLength;
}
class Zebra extends Animal{
    int numOfStripes;
}
class Zoo{
    List<Giraffe> giraffes=new ArrayList<Giraffe>();
   List<Zebra> zebras=new ArrayList<Zebra>();
   public void printMostAnimals(){
       for(Animal a: getMostAnimals()){
           System.out.println(a);
       }
   }

    private List<? extends Animal> getMostAnimals() {
        if(giraffes.size()>zebras.size())
            return giraffes;
        return zebras;
    }

    public void mate(List<? extends Animal>animals) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
       if(animals.size()>2){
           Class<?> firstAnimalInstanceClass=animals.get(0).getClass();

               Animal newAnimal=(Animal)firstAnimalInstanceClass.newInstance();
                animals.add(newAnimal);
              // animals.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("add",Object.class).invoke(animals,newAnimal);
               System.out.println("new mate was added");
               return;
       }
        System.out.println("no mate been added");
    }
}

class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Zoo z=new Zoo();
        z.zebras.add(new Zebra());
        z.zebras.add(new Zebra());
        z.zebras.add(new Zebra());
        z.mate(z.zebras);
        System.out.println("new zebra been added?"+(z.zebras.size()>3));

    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try reading about a topic called type erasure.

Comment: that have nothing to do with type erasure.. but with the conformance of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to add an Animal "*aa*" to a `List<Giraffe>` because "*aa*" could be a `Zebra`.

When you declare a `List<? extends Animal>`, you tell the compiler that it is a a `List<Giraffe>`, a `List<Zebra>` or a `List<Animal>`. Since it could be a `List<Giraffe>`, we fall in the case above, which means that you cannot add an `Animal`.

If you **remove the generic**, it should work, because you tell the compiler that there could be **anything** in the list:

```
((List)animals).add(newAnimal);
```

However you **loose all type safety**.

---

Instead why not do it as follows:

```
class AnimalList<AnimalType extends Animal> extends List<AnimalType> {
   void mate() {
      Class<AnimalType> firstAnimalInstanceClass = animals.get(0).getClass();
      AnimalType newAnimal = (AnimalType)firstAnimalInstanceClass.newInstance();
      add(newAnimal);
   }
}
```

In your Zoo, you would declare:

```
AnimalList<Zebra>
AnimalList<Giraffe>
```

and then call `mate` without arguments:

```
AnimalList<? extends Animal> list;
list.mate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because somebody might write:

```
List<Giraffe> giraffes = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Animal> animals = giraffes;
animals.add(new Zebra());

for (Giraffe g : giraffes) { // but there is a Zebra in there!
    g.eatLeavesFrom(tallTree); // Zebras can't do that!
}
```

To have type safety when mating, you could do:

```
class Animal<M extends Animal<M>> {
    M mate;
}

class Giraffe extends Animal<Giraffe> {}
class Zebra extends Animal<Zebra> {}
```

which allows you to write:

```
<A extends Animal<A>> void matingSeason(List<A> animals) {
    A x = null;
    for (A a : animals) {
        if (x != null) {
            a.mate = x;
            x.mate = a;
            x = null;
        } else {
            x = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot add anything other than `null` to `List<? extends Animal>`.

Ex:

```
    void foo(List<? extends Animal> animals ){
    animals.add(new Animal());// compiler error
}
```

let's assume for a minute it doesn't raise a compiler error and i call `foo(new ArrayList<Dog>())`, it will add `Animal` to a `List` of dogs. clearly that shouldn't be allowed and thus the above code won't compile.

if this didn't raise an error the whole point of generic compile time safety is gone.

Comment: @AviadShiber, no you can't .give a minute to update the answer to make it more clear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130760/why-java-compiler-restricts-adding-even-the-right-type-of-element-to-the-list-wh/37131161#37131161

Comment: Thanks, I now get it :).
so when I create a List<? extends anyClass> it must be readOnly?